# AJAX function returning -1

Tags: jquery, ajax

I recently developed a small plugin for my site, that uses AJAX, and now I am trying to implement the same AJAX techniques for the same site's templates, but I keep getting `-1` as the result, here is my code,

functions.php:

```
    //Front end AJAX functions

    function eu_custom_query(){
        global $post;
        global $wpdb;

        echo "yo";

        die();
    }

function enque_template_scripts() {

    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );


    // embed the javascript file that makes the AJAX request
    wp_register_script( 'scripts.js', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/scripts/scripts.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts.js' );

    // declare the URL to the file that handles the AJAX request (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php)
    wp_localize_script( 'scripts.js', 'wp_ajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); 

}    


    add_action('wp_ajax_custom_query', 'eu_custom_query');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_query', 'eu_custom_query');
    add_action('get_header', 'enque_template_scripts');
```

scripts.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#do_ajax").click(function(){
            $.post(wp_ajax.ajaxurl, { action: 'eu_custom_query' }, function(data){
                alert(data);
            });
    });
});
```

I'm using Wordpress version 3.2.1

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing 'eu_custom_query' as the action in your AJAX. It should be 'custom_query'.

You decide the action name, when you add the action i.e. 'wp_ajax_my_action' would be called 'my_action'

You are confusing it with the callback method. Hope that makes sense.

p.s. to fix your code change:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_query', 'eu_custom_query');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_query', 'eu_custom_query');
```

to:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_eu_custom_query', 'eu_custom_query');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_eu_custom_query', 'eu_custom_query');
```

Comment: Oooh my word! I can't believe I missed that! Thanks for pointing it out, that was the problem.

Comment: You just needed a fresh pair of eyes. :)

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues:

**noConflict**

WordPress [requires noConflict wrappers for jQuery](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers). So this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

...needs to be this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

...so that `$` will work properly inside the function.

**Blanket replacement of core-bundled script**

Also, you are nakedly replacing the core-bundled jQuery, which you should *never do*, or you will risk breaking things in the WP-Admin backend.

Any such code **must** be wrapped inside an `if ( ! is_admin() )` conditional:

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```